# Is there a Desktop that allows for certain workspaces to be tiling?

Tags: window-manager, desktop-environment, workspaces, tiling-wm

I am interested in trying out a tiling window manager, but I also like a conventional desktop.

Are there any desktop environments where you can specify a certain work space to using tiling windows, and another workspace to use a conventional approach?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a recipe for that, but I can tell you where to look. [Awesome](https://awesomewm.org/) and [Sawfish](http://sawfish.tuxfamily.org/) are programmable window managers, where the bulk of the code is written in a high-level language and is easy to plug into. Awesome is written in Lua and Sawfish is written in a Lisp-Scheme hybrid.

Awesome (which I've never used) leans towards tiling, but also supports floating window layouts out of the box. You can define rules to apply to each window. Awesome's documentation tends to avoid the word “workspace” and uses “tags” instead: at any given time, the screen displays all the windows with a certain set of tags, which effectively means that Awesome has workspaces such that a window can be in multiple workspaces. There's an example of [rules](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.rules.html) in the documentation to define certain windows as tiled and others as floating.

Sawfish (which I've used for a long time) only supports floating windows out of the box, but can also be [programmed for tiling](https://sawfish.fandom.com/wiki/Tiling_placement). Sawfish has classical workspaces (but allows a window to be on multiple workspaces). Sawfish development has been inactive since 2017, so I wouldn't recommend it anymore, even though I'm personally happy with it.

Awesome and Sawfish are just [window managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager), not [desktop environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment). You can get a complete desktop environment by manually running the pieces that the window manager doesn't provide, such as a system tray and various system tray widgets (I've used at least lxpanel, xfce4-panel, gnome-panel over the years and don't have any particular recommendation).